# Slice dates in a pandas dataframe and convert to string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a CAS number Column, this column comes from a Excel sheet. When I copied the Column into the Excel sheet some of the values changed into a date format and I need to change that back.

Example: CAS before copying 2391-07-1, after copying 2391-07-01 00:00:00

I need to convert these date values back, there are also CAS numbers that didn't change (already good) and some NaN, which should be left as they are.

My dataframe (or for this column the series) looks something like this but with many more entries:

```
0   3483-12-03 00:00:00
1   Nan
2   364-41-4
3   9013-02-09 00:00:00
```

I need it to look like this:

```
0   3483-12-3
1   NaN
2   364-41-4
3   9013-02-9
```

I tried it by slicing the values for each row but that didn't really work out.

Thanks for any help in advance :-)

Comment: That's an XY Problem. You asking about how to fix your approach rather than how to fix the real cause of the problem. It seems like you need to read this column as a string, such that pandas avoids to "guess" its type. When reading, explcitly state that, i.e. `pdf.read_excel('file.xlsx', dtype={'column_name': str})`

Comment: The data is formated as dates in the excel sheet already and I want to convert that back with pandas, sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: how do you read the excel to pandas?

Comment: df = pd.read_excel('path')

Comment: The Columns are all formated as strings once they are read by pandas to a dataframe, the problem with the date fromat already comes up when the data is inserted to the excel file i read with pandas